# How do I delete an item previously border

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this short example:

[link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxqaXW)

```
<fieldset id="packType">
    <label>1</label>
    <label>2</label>
    <label>3</label>
</fieldset>
```

```js
$("#packType label").on("click", function(e) {
    $(this).css({ "border": "2px solid #ff4141" });
});
```

I want to apply a red border only on the item that you click and the remainder should have `border: none;`. How can I do this? Can you help me please?

Comment: This is exactly why it's better to set your CSS in classes then use `addClass()` and `removeClass()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```js
var $lbl = $("#packType label").on("click", function(e) {
  $lbl.css("border", "none");
  // set border none to all elements
  $(this).css("border", "2px solid #ff4141");
  // set border to clicked element
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset id="packType">
  <label>1</label>
  <label>2</label>
  <label>3</label>
</fieldset>
```

Or using [`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/), which selects siblings of the elements

```js
$("#packType label").on("click", function(e) {
  $(this).css("border", "2px solid #ff4141")
  //set border to clicked element
    .siblings().css("border", "none");
    // set border none to all siblings of clicked element
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset id="packType">
  <label>1</label>
  <label>2</label>
  <label>3</label>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the border to clicked element and use `.siblings()` selector to select other element and set respective border to none.

```js
 $("#packType label").on("click", function(e) {
   $(this).css({
     "border": "2px solid #ff4141"
   });
   $(this).siblings().css({
     "border": "none"
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset id="packType">
  <label>1</label>
  <label>2</label>
  <label>3</label>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are no other styles on the labels then you can remove the style attribute completely use this:

```
$(this).css({ "border": "2px solid #ff4141" })
       .siblings('label').removeAttr('style'); // will clean the style attribute.
```

If you need to use other styles and just targeting the borders to be removed use this:

```
$(this).css({ "border": "2px solid #ff4141" })
       .siblings('label').css('border','none'); // will remove borders.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a CSS class, the add the CSS class to current clicked label.

To get the desired result various APIs can be used i.e. `.siblings()`, `addClass()` and `removeClass()`

```js
$("#packType label").on("click", function(e) {
  $(this).addClass('withBorder').siblings().removeClass('withBorder');
});
```

```css
.withBorder {
  border: 2px solid #ff4141;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset id="packType">
  <label>1</label>
  <label>2</label>
  <label>3</label>
</fieldset>
```